Emacs flycheck lsp include paths
I use LSP for code completion with Emacs for C++ development.
My project is quite big and has few 1000s of source files.
I have generated compile_commands.json, but using flycheck-compile explicitly
doesn't help it to get the custom include paths & pre-processor macros.
Have worked around this by including custom include paths & macros
using .dir-locals.el inside project root area. This requires mentioning
the include paths explicitly.
However, I feel there must be a way to find the include paths & macros
through lsp itself. How can I let flycheck use lsp to get these info rather
than depending on .dir-locals.el ? This way an extra management for .dir-locals
won't be required.
Tried flycheck-compile in Emacs for C++.
